# How to suppress Rxjs unhandled exception logging?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a stream implemented using Rxjs which may fail, and in the case that it does, I need the stream to close and to be able to handle the error for a graceful shutdown.

The `error` callback in the subscribe method does everything I want, but rxjs has built-in error reporting which I would like to suppress so that my code can handle this with more intentionality.

IIRC, the `catchError` operator would suppress this logging but it keeps the stream alive and would complicate dependent code as I would have to pipe out error information differently to trigger my error handling code elsewhere.

Is there a straight-forward way to suppress unhandled exception logging for rxjs while avoiding use of `catchError` so that I can handle error reporting my own way in the subscribe method's `error` callback?

Edit: as it turns out the situation was a little more serious than unnecessary logging.  The pipeline was throwing exceptions asynchronously which could not be caught at top-level code, and were crashing the program before cleanup operations could complete.  While ideally I would prefer to rely on the error callback in this scenario, I opted to fall back to the catchError operator used in a dependency prior to subscription, to prevent application crashes.

I'm leaving this question open for now in case anyone has a better answer.

Comment: Your question in missing a code example, it would help if you added it. Also, you can answer your own questions in an answer instead of in the question.

Comment: "_rxjs has built-in error reporting_" - could you be more clear about this built-in error reporting? A code example would make it easier to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do something like this

```
observable.pipe(
tap({
  error: () => console.log('move your callback from subscribe here')
}),
catchError( () => EMPTY))
.subscribe()
```

Everything in your subscribe can be move in the tap.